# How can I over-ride my Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger that updates a lead field with a new value. In Apex, is there a way that I can code in a manual over-ride into the trigger? For example: If a salesperson manually enters a value into that field, the trigger will never fire again on that lead?

Much appreciated,
Alex

Comment: Do you want the trigger not to fire whenever this field is populated or only when Salesperson changes it?

Comment: specifically when a salesperson populates it with a new value other than the "triggered' value. From that point on the trigger should not run again. (unless the field is manually set to null) @AmrIbrahim

Comment: What distinguishes a salesperson, is it a profile or role?

Comment: A role I suppose. I used "salesperson" for example's sake. Really, any human in the organization should be able to enter a manual over-ride. @AmrIbrahim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a logical condition to execute the trigger accordingly. For instance

```
If(trigger.old.field == null && trigger.new.lastmodifiedby != API user){
    //fire trigger logic
}
```

Based on your organization you can specify the condition that differentiates human from non-human interaction (e.g. user name of api user or profile).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This may be a novel question, but where would I find the API of the user, profile, or role? Or do I simply write "API user"?

Comment: In regards to the part: "trigger.new.lastmodifiedby"

Is it possible to specify the exact field that is being modified, as opposed to the lead in general? The staff should still be able to edit the lead without the trigger being disabled. It should only be disabled if they edit a particular field. @Amr Ibrahim

Comment: Writing API user will not work ... it depends on your environment ... can this field be updated via API? what user is used to update API?
Answer to your second question is yes you can specify the field.

Comment: The field should be updated by API (trigger) by default. If any user were to override the trigger generated field, the trigger should be disabled and the manual entry should take superiority. @AmrIbrahim

Comment: I am confused ... API is different than trigger. API means that the field is updated via integration process. Updating via trigger can be called system update.

Comment: These are all new terms to me. I would just like to know what I should write instead of "API User" in the code you've provided.  Every user in my organization should have the ability to over-ride the trigger with a manual entry.